Does any browser supports cryptex (rfc 9335)?
I've noticed that some WebRTC libraries implement Cryptex from RFC 9335 for encrypting RTP packets. However, I haven't seen any browsers that support it yet. Am I overlooking something?
Implementing this in a Selective Forwarding Unit (SFU) is challenging if browsers don't support it.
